# Controlling the sampling from Variational AutoEncoder (VAE)

Tags: sampling, vae

Suppose a Variational Autoencoder (VAE) is trained with mnist data. To sample, one draws from normal distribution. My question is: suppose I am interested in generating only 1s and no other digits. How can do I do that? do I sample until I generate a 1 and then I keep sampling from the neighborhood of that point? or is there a more controlled way to tell the VAE what digit to generate? Thanks

Edit*

The ideal encoder would take any input and generate a sample coming from $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. If the input is 1 or 2 or 3, the samplings will all come from $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, so, how does the decoder know if the input was 1, 2, or 3?

Comment: there are 2 approaches, one is sample unitll you get a 1, the other is to have some input point in latent space whose representation is close to 1. In both cases you will have to check you get indeed a 1 back

Comment: about the second approach, if the encoder truly does his job, shouldn't the output of the encoder just be $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ but it will be the same for digit 2, 3, etc.

Comment: to my understanding "close" input points should have "close" output representations, if this is what you mean. A 3rd option is to train a VAE only with 1s

Comment: I edited my question to clarify what I mean, please let me know if it's clear or I should clarify further.

Comment: Are [conditional VAEs](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2015/hash/8d55a249e6baa5c06772297520da2051-Abstract.html) an option?

Comment: @Sammy yes, I could look into that, but now I'd rather stay with simple VAE.

Comment: does this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/369660/when-generating-samples-using-variational-autoencoder-we-decode-samples-from-n answer your question?

Comment: Your previous answer already answered my question. But thanks for adding that extra explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You condition the latent variable on another variable drawn from a categorical distribution (https://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2016/12/17/conditional-vae/).